# Keyboard shortcut for renaming tabs in the Terminator terminal emulator?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminator

In the 'Terminator' terminal emulator I can rename windows using: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Does anyone know of a keyboard shortcut (or how to create one) for renaming tabs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Titles can be set using:

| Edit | Default Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Window title | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> |
| Tab title | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> |
| Terminal title | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> |

Source: the Terminator official documentation, in the [Setting Titles](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#setting-titles) section

Note: you may run into issues
with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> hiding the window instead. 
Right click inside the terminal and go to **preferences→keybindings**
and change **hide_window** to something else.